# If the browser enforces a Sandox, then why the infections by malware?

Tags: malware, web-browser, javascript, virus, vulnerability

By design the browser enforces a Sandbox, but we know that Javascript which runs inside this sandbox can be used to do malware damage etc.Isn't the sandbox supposed to protect against it as well as against other vulnerabilities like those found in browser addons, Flash for example?

Is it because the browser's sandbox model is just not good enough?

Is it because the browser can have access to the filesystem? Some malware is downloaded as a result of a drive by download and end up in the browser's Cache directory or in other temporary directories.After it is downloaded how is this malware file actually run/executed by the OS and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox enviornment in browser is designed to restrict the anything from within the browser to cause any harm to your computer. It gives the browser low rights, so that any malicious code(Javascript) cannot harm your system files. But, whenever you are explicitly downloading any files or giving explicit rights(by clicking on yes, when an alert appears), you are giving the malicious code access, to do anything with your files.

Bottomline: The sandbox env, protects the system unless you tell it to give rights to certain programs to do harm.